# How to divide or cut a YUV file?

Tags: yuv

I have a YUV file with 150 frames, I want to divide it into 2 files of 75 frames each. How to go bu doing this ? Are there any software's to do this ?

Answer (score 4):

No specific SW is needed. All you need to do is read/write the number of bytes that corresponds to a frame into a new file. "Normally" the YCbCr format used is subsampled according to 4:2:0, i.e. the chroma samples are reduced by a factor of 2 both horizontally and vertically; meaning that  1 frame in YCbCr 4:2:0 corresponds to

```
1 frame = width x height x 3 / 2 bytes
```

If you are on a linux based system, you can use the `dd` utility to extract the first n-frames into a new file like this:

```
dd if=input.yuv bs=1 count=$((width*height*3/2*num_frames)) of=output.yuv
```

for the first 10 frames of a 1080p clip, the above would be:

```
dd if=input.yuv bs=1 count=$((1920*1080*3/2*10)) of=output.yuv
```

or

```
dd if=input.yuv bs=1 count=3110400 of=output.yuv
```

or use your favorite programming/scripting language to do this.

For example, the following python-scripts writes the first 10 frames to a new file (one frame at a time), tweek it to your needs:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

f_in = 'BQMall_832x480_60.yuv'
f_out = 'BQMall_first_10_frames.yuv'
f_size = 832*480*3/2

with open(f_in, 'rb') as fd_in, open(f_out, 'wb') as fd_out:
    for i in range(10):
        data = fd_in.read(f_size)
        fd_out.write(data)
```

Comment: In this command dd if=input.yuv bs=1 count=$((1920*1080*3/2*10)) of=output.yuv
I had to give 135 num_frames to obtain a 90 frame file. Why is it so ?

Comment: most likely due to that your YCbCr-file is not in 4:2:0 format but in 4:2:2. Then you need to change the calculation to `$((1920*1080*2*10))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that "do not use `bs = 1`"

```
 dd if=176x144.yuv bs= $((176 * 144 * 3 / 2)) count=$FrameNo of=output.yuv
```